# git config file - fatal: bad config file line 12 in .git/config

Tags: git, git-config

I am getting error `fatal: bad config file line 12 in .git/config` when I run any git command to do with `git config`, except when I am in /c/Windows/System32. I have tried running git bash as admin and it doesn't make a difference.

When I look at my .gitconfig file in /c/Users// it looks like:

```
[core]
symlinks = false
autocrlf = true
[color]
diff = auto
status = auto
branch = auto
interactive = true
[pack]
packSizeLimit = 2g
[help]
format = html
[http]
sslCAinfo = /bin/<file>
[https]
proxy=<internal proxy>
[user]
name=<name>
email=<email>
[sendemail]
smtpserver = /bin/<file>
[diff "astextplain"]
textconv = astextplain
[rebase]
autosquash = true
```

Of course with the `<name>, <internal proxy>, <file> and <email>` are replaced with the correct details. Also, the file has a file type of `GITCONFIG` File and is called `.gitconfig`.

My gitconfig file in /etc/ looks like:

```
[core]
symlinks = false
autocrlf = true
[color]
diff = auto
status = auto
branch = auto
interactive = true
[pack]
packSizeLimit = 2g
[http]
sslCAinfo = /bin/<file>
[https]
proxy=<internal proxy>
[user]
name=<name>
email=<email>
[sendemail]
smtpserver = /bin/<file>
[diff "astextplain"]
textconv = astextplain
[rebase]
autosquash = true
```

Again, the `<name>, <internal proxy>, <file> and <email>` are replaced with the correct details. In this case, the file has a file type of `File` and is called `gitconfig`.

Can anyone please help resolve my issues so I can continue running git commands?

Comment: Notice that the error points at a file named `.git/config`. Neither file you have posted here seems to be that file.

Comment: The error message specifies that the problem is in the repo's local configuration file.  This should only be possible when git perceives you to be in the working tree of a repository, so based on your report of when this happens I wonder if you have a `.git` directory at your `C:` root directory?

Comment: In any event, whenever you get this error you can say `git rev-parse --git-dir` and it will point you to a directory.  `cd` to that directory, and you should find it contains a file simply named `config`.  That file should contain the error (so if it's still unclear what's wrong, you'd need to post content of that file)

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this questions is that I had not run `git init` inside the intended repository folder and therefore there was no repository.

Comment: That condition will not lead to the described symptom unless there are additional problems.